# keyup does not work at dynamic added field

Tags: jquery, html

I have form which have dynamically added fields. I want to show typed content in one input into another `field` with script like this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#field').keyup(function(){
      $('#target').html($(this).val());
    });
    $('#field_2').keyup(function(){
      $('#target2').html($(this).val());
    });

  });
</script>
```

as long as all works on the first field problem is with the second one because typed characters are not being showed in the `target2` label.

[Here is JSFidle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mithrand1r/5fr9X/)

Could anyone give me a hint how Can I make text typed into 1st added input show in the 2nd label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to delegate the event to the static closest parent with `.on()` method:

```
$('#buildyourform').on('keyup', '#field_2', function(){
    $('#target2').html($(this).val());
});
```

#### [demo @ Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5fr9X/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to delegate like this:

```
$('form').on("keyup", "#field", function(){..});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not work for dynamicaly added objects. Use instead:

```
$('#field_container').on("keyup", "#field", function(){
  $('#target').html($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really cool problem.
You need to use .on event, however, more precisely a solution to your problem would be:

```
$('#buildyourform').on("keyup", ".textComesFromThisInput", function(){
    var index = $('#buildyourform').index($(this).parent());
    var targetDiv = $(':nth-child('+index+')');
    targetDiv.find('label').html($(this).val());
});


<div id="buildyourform">form</div>
    <div class="parentOfTextInputs">
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="textComesFromThisInput">
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="parentOfTargetTextLabelsAndInputs">
        <div>
            <label class="textGoesInThisLabel"></label>
            <input type="text" class=".thisInputDoesNothing">
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

That's all the js you need to write if you build your html like that. When you press the arrow to add new items, you just append a div with label and input in it, to .parentOfTargetTextLablesAndInputs
You check which input coresponds to which label using :nth-child()

This could work for an infinite nr of items added by that arrow with no additional js.

Have fun.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$(document).on("keyup","#field2_2", function() {
     // do something    
});
```